# Angular doesn't pass string variable to boolean expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS function that uses JavaScript's `RegExp()` to look for a character at the start of a string. In this case, it's a lowercase `p`.

```
    $scope.checkState = function(state){
      var page = state;
      console.log(page);
      var regex = new RegExp("^[p]");
      var check = regex.exec(page);
      console.log('Regex evaluated to: ' + check);
      if (check == "p")
        return false;
      else
        return true;
    }
```

On the main HTML page, there is a button that is checking for an answer to the status of `checkState()`. If it returns as false, it hides the button from view with `ng-show`.

```
<md-button class="md-raised md-warn btn-right" ng-show="checkState({{pageID}})" ng-model="thing" ng-cloak onclick="thing()">My Button</md-button>
```

In here, `pageID` is a variable that contains a given ID value of a page template. When called in Angular, `pageID` becomes a string that is passed to the `checkState()` function.

Right now, I have been able to get the script to evaluate to `null`, but not to any other results. This is because despite the variable being filled in programatically, I get `undefined` instead.

***What's going on here?***

Comment: but you can simply do `ng-show="checkState(pageID)"` and that should work

Comment: Was just about to say, most any Angular directive will track these changes with each digest cycle. I don't know if that's the core problem, but it could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many thanks to @entre and @Harris Weinstein for their help. The problem was here:

`ng-show="checkState({{pageID}})"`

I had incorrectly thought that I needed to use the curly braces in order to get the string I needed. However, Angular doesn't need that when using its own function calls. Therefore, the correct way to pass the string is:

`ng-show="checkState(pageID)"`